# Setting an AD user active by default (on creation)

Tags: active-directory, adlds

I wrote some code (Java and LDAP) to create a user in the Active directory.
Is it possible to set a user active by default (when he is created)
in the active directory when I create him or do I have to modify the user?
(the user will always have a pass when created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the user has a password, you can enable the account at creation by setting `userAccountControl` to `512`. It's possible you might need to do this in a second LDAP call depending on how your creation/password set code works.

Comment: The problem isn't enabling the user, I already know how to do that. What I'd like to know is: can you configure active directory to automatically enable created users?